Handling system errors with large dataset in looker studio
I'm facing system errors in Looker studio when connecting a bigquery table  of approximately 9.3 billion records.
I tried connecting the same table with  around 2 million records then it worked fine. How can I fix or work around these errors for large datasets in Looker studio?

Unfortunately looker is limited to 5k rows and i think 100mb of data a day (it might be lower now). I suspect 9 billion rows will be to much for Looker pro, power BI and tableau. I would seek to aggregate your data in  Big query and then push to Looker.

But it works fine when i connect looker studio with big query table containing 1 Million records.

And also in case of looker studio connecting with the table  containing 9 billion records, when I continuously refresh the calculated fields for any specific chart the errors gets resolved for those charts. So why is it happening then?

I suspect you are not seeing all of the values for the 9 billion records but only a subset, but if you are looker will be lazy loading and so not automatically refreshing. I would still recommend aggregation or partitioning of your data to make the dashboard faster
